# How does macro function in c uses the pass by reference

Tags: c

I' m learning Macro in c,
I wrote a small function in macro to swap number, but passed the value as 'pass by value' since i didn't use address of operator (&) before the variable in the argument, But when i ran the program. The value got swaped. You can refer the code and mention me where i got wrong in understanding?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define swap(a,b) a = a+b;b = a-b; a = a-b;
int main()
{
    int x = 5, y = 10;
    swap(x,y);
    printf("%d %d\n",x,y);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Do the arguments acts as pass by reference, when using it in macro?

Comment: A macro is not a function, to begin with

Comment: A macro is something the compiler replaces every occurrence of with its definition at run time. There is no scope difference

Comment: ok i get it, in place of swap(x,y) the #defined swap(a,b) part would be replaced.@StoryTeller Thank you

Comment: As a side note, this is a very dangerous macro, because it is vulnerable to operator precedence issues. I'd recommend reading up about macros in a C book, it will point out this problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C doesn't have pass-by-reference. And that's not what's happening here anyway. When a macro is "called", the preprocessor *replaces* the call-site with the body.

With your example, the invocation

```
swap(x,y);
```

is replaced by

```
x = x+y;y = x-y; x = x-y;;
```

This last line is what the actual parser of the compiler sees.

Many compilers have options to stop after the preprocessing step. I suggest you use that to see exactly what the preprocessor have done.

---

I also hope you start to see how macros can "break" your code.

For example if the code was

```
if (some_condition)
    swap(x,y);
```

Then it would be *expanded* to (with some reformatting)

```
if (some_condition)
    x = x+y;
y = x-y;
x = x-y;
;
```

This is clearly not what was intended and will not work.

You also have the case when the arguments to the macro are not simple variables, but expressions. Like

```
swap(x+1,y*2)
```

While would be replaced by

```
x+1 = x+1+y*2;y*2 = x+1-y*2; x+1 = x+1-y*2;;
```

This also would not work.

Comment: Thanks you i got the concept.